# Struggling with a uncooperative unpivot

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got the a table that has a large number of columns, and looks like this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [EXTVOLUMELABELID]
  ,[FCVOLUMEDRVRID]
  ,[BUSINESSDT]
  ,[H00I1]
  ,[H00I2]
  ,[H00I3]
  ,[H00I4]
  ,[H01I1]
  ,[H01I2]
  ,[H01I3]
  ,[H01I4]
  ,[H02I1]
  ,[H02I2]
  ,[H02I3]
  ,[H02I4]
  ,[H03I1]
  ,[H03I2]
  ,[H03I3]
  ,[H03I4]
  ,[H04I1]
  ,[H04I2]
  ,[H04I3]
  ,[H04I4]
  ,[H05I1]
  ,[H05I2]
  ,[H05I3]
  ,[H05I4]
  ,[H06I1]
  ,[H06I2]
  ,[H06I3]
  ,[H06I4]
  ,[H07I1]
  ,[H07I2]
  ,[H07I3]
  ,[H07I4]
  ,[H08I1]
  ,[H08I2]
  ,[H08I3]
  ,[H08I4]
  ,[H09I1]
  ,[H09I2]
  ,[H09I3]
  ,[H09I4]
  ,[H10I1]
  ,[H10I2]
  ,[H10I3]
  ,[H10I4]
  ,[H11I1]
  ,[H11I2]
  ,[H11I3]
  ,[H11I4]
  ,[H12I1]
  ,[H12I2]
  ,[H12I3]
  ,[H12I4]
  ,[H13I1]
  ,[H13I2]
  ,[H13I3]
  ,[H13I4]
  ,[H14I1]
  ,[H14I2]
  ,[H14I3]
  ,[H14I4]
  ,[H15I1]
  ,[H15I2]
  ,[H15I3]
  ,[H15I4]
  ,[H16I1]
  ,[H16I2]
  ,[H16I3]
  ,[H16I4]
  ,[H17I1]
  ,[H17I2]
  ,[H17I3]
  ,[H17I4]
  ,[H18I1]
  ,[H18I2]
  ,[H18I3]
  ,[H18I4]
  ,[H19I1]
  ,[H19I2]
  ,[H19I3]
  ,[H19I4]
  ,[H20I1]
  ,[H20I2]
  ,[H20I3]
  ,[H20I4]
  ,[H21I1]
  ,[H21I2]
  ,[H21I3]
  ,[H21I4]
  ,[H22I1]
  ,[H22I2]
  ,[H22I3]
  ,[H22I4]
  ,[H23I1]
  ,[H23I2]
  ,[H23I3]
  ,[H23I4]
  ,[OFFSETFROMMIDNIGHTNUM]
  ,[UPDATEDTM]
  FROM [POSVOLUMEHIST]
```

I'd like the output format to only have the following columns:

EXTVOLUMEID, BUSINESSDT, TIME (aliased from columns that look like this: H00I2 etc), value (values from time columns)

I have this so far:

```
USE tkcsdb

SELECT  ORGREPORT.ORGNM
  ,CONVERT (DATE, POS.BUSINESSDT) As 'Date'
  ,start_time
  ,footfall_count


  FROM POSVOLUMEHIST POS

  JOIN FCCATEGORY CAT
  ON POS.EXTVOLUMELABELID = CAT.EXTVOLUMELABELID

  JOIN ORG ORG
  ON CAT.ORGIDSID = ORG.ORGIDSID

  JOIN ORG ORGREPORT
  ON ORG.REPORTTOORGID = ORGREPORT.ORGIDSID

UNPIVOT (footfall_count for start_time in

(      POS.H08I1
  ,POS.H08I2
  ,POS.H08I3
  ,POS.H08I4
  ,POS.H09I1
  ,POS.H09I2
  ,POS.H09I3
  ,POS.H09I4
  ,POS.H10I1
  ,POS.H10I2
  ,POS.H10I3
  ,POS.H10I4
  ,POS.H11I1
  ,POS.H11I2
  ,POS.H11I3
  ,POS.H11I4
  ,POS.H12I1
  ,POS.H12I2
  ,POS.H12I3
  ,POS.H12I4
  ,POS.H13I1
  ,POS.H13I2
  ,POS.H13I3
  ,POS.H13I4
  ,POS.H14I1
  ,POS.H14I2
  ,POS.H14I3
  ,POS.H14I4
  ,POS.H15I1
  ,POS.H15I2
  ,POS.H15I3
  ,POS.H15I4
  ,POS.H16I1
  ,POS.H16I2
  ,POS.H16I3
  ,POS.H16I4
  ,POS.H17I1
  ,POS.H17I2
  ,POS.H17I3
  ,POS.H17I4
  ,POS.H18I1
  ,POS.H18I2
  ,POS.H18I3
  ,POS.H18I4
  ,POS.H19I1
  ,POS.H19I2
  ,POS.H19I3
  ,POS.H19I4
  ,POS.H20I1
  ,POS.H20I2
  ,POS.H20I3
  ,POS.H20I4
  ,POS.H21I1
  ,POS.H21I2
  ,POS.H21I3
  ,POS.H21I4
  ,POS.H22I1
))


  WHERE

  CAST (POS.BUSINESSDT as Date) >= 'Mar 26, 2018'

  AND

  CAST (POS.BUSINESSDT as Date) <= 'Apr 01, 2018'

    ORDER BY ORGREPORT.ORGNM, POS.BUSINESSDT;
```

I keep getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

I can't work out why this doesn't work. I can't remove the where clause to test as it will return millions of results.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for PIVOT is :

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

As you can see, you can't have a `WHERE` clause following or preceding a `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` clause.

To overcome this, move the WHERE logic in a nested query:

```
USE tkcsdb

SELECT  ORGREPORT.ORGNM
  ,CONVERT (DATE, POS.BUSINESSDT) As 'Date'
  ,start_time
  ,footfall_count


  FROM 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM POSVOLUMEHIST 
    WHERE CAST (BUSINESSDT as Date) >= 'Mar 26, 2018'
      AND CAST (BUSINESSDT as Date) <= 'Apr 01, 2018'
  ) POS

  JOIN FCCATEGORY CAT
  ON POS.EXTVOLUMELABELID = CAT.EXTVOLUMELABELID

  JOIN ORG ORG
  ON CAT.ORGIDSID = ORG.ORGIDSID

  JOIN ORG ORGREPORT
  ON ORG.REPORTTOORGID = ORGREPORT.ORGIDSID

UNPIVOT (footfall_count for start_time in

(      POS.H08I1
  ,POS.H08I2
  ,POS.H08I3
  ,POS.H08I4
  ,POS.H09I1
  ,POS.H09I2
  ,POS.H09I3
  ,POS.H09I4
  ,POS.H10I1
  ,POS.H10I2
  ,POS.H10I3
  ,POS.H10I4
  ,POS.H11I1
  ,POS.H11I2
  ,POS.H11I3
  ,POS.H11I4
  ,POS.H12I1
  ,POS.H12I2
  ,POS.H12I3
  ,POS.H12I4
  ,POS.H13I1
  ,POS.H13I2
  ,POS.H13I3
  ,POS.H13I4
  ,POS.H14I1
  ,POS.H14I2
  ,POS.H14I3
  ,POS.H14I4
  ,POS.H15I1
  ,POS.H15I2
  ,POS.H15I3
  ,POS.H15I4
  ,POS.H16I1
  ,POS.H16I2
  ,POS.H16I3
  ,POS.H16I4
  ,POS.H17I1
  ,POS.H17I2
  ,POS.H17I3
  ,POS.H17I4
  ,POS.H18I1
  ,POS.H18I2
  ,POS.H18I3
  ,POS.H18I4
  ,POS.H19I1
  ,POS.H19I2
  ,POS.H19I3
  ,POS.H19I4
  ,POS.H20I1
  ,POS.H20I2
  ,POS.H20I3
  ,POS.H20I4
  ,POS.H21I1
  ,POS.H21I2
  ,POS.H21I3
  ,POS.H21I4
  ,POS.H22I1
)) 
    ORDER BY ORGREPORT.ORGNM, POS.BUSINESSDT;
```

Comment: Thank you, very well explained. I'm still getting erros though. This leaves me with the following error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Removing the Order by line gives the following error: 

Incorrect syntax near ')'.